# Dummy Audio Output [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS]

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

To start, initially I'd purchased a headset and connected it to my laptop running on Ubuntu 18.04.1LTS with no audio coming out.

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html 
I followed this and things worked for a while, now things dont work anymore? The dialogue box had headphone written on it even when I didnt have it connected, of course with no audio coming out of the laptop either.

I attempted to remedy this by making the edit suggested in the end of that file (mode=auto edit)

Now it's back to dummy output again

Any tips?